# what's the difference between -> and => in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

today  I follow the rails guide and run a demo which include a `scope` as below:

```
scope :me, =>(keyword){where("title = ?",keyword)}
```

but it not work,so I change to :

```
scope :me, ->(keyword){where("title = ?",keyword)}
```

now it works,so I want to know the  the difference between `->` and `=>` in rails
but I didn't find the result,so please tell me,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=>` separates the keys from the values in a hashmap literal

`->` - new `lambda` (syntactic sugar)

Examples :

```
h = { "foo" => "bar" }
l = ->{ "hello" }
l.call # => "hello"
```

Comment: why is it `# => "hello"` and not `# -> "hello"` ? :)

Comment: That's because there no such thing as lambda return in ruby :)

Answer (score 2):

The first is a syntax error. Wherever you read that, it's completely wrong.

The second is commonly known as 'stabby lambda syntax' - its a shortcut for writing:

```
lambda { |keyword| where('title = ?', keyword) }
```

More about lambdas in Ruby: http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/34-lambdas-and-blocks-in-ruby/lessons/77-lambdas-in-ruby